# Image displaying differently in different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, mobile

[image: Image as seen in 1366x760 screen]

[image: Image as seen in 1920x1080 screen]

The problem for me is the same image is seen differently in different browser settings. The section below the first image appears in the 1080p resolution screen and I don't see a way to mitigate this. Any idea how to do this?

This is the .css file

```
/* Home Style */
```

## tf-home{

```
background: url(../images/OdysseyTitleImage.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #cfcfcf;
```

}

## tf-home .overlay{

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height: 750px;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

}

This is the relevant html code

```
<div id="tf-home" class="text-center">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="content">
            <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRlP0t41wCw" class="btn tf-btn btn-default popup-video">Watch the trailer</a></div>
            <a href="#tf-game" class="fa fa-angle-down page-scroll"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tf-game">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container content-game">
            <div class="section-title">
                <h1 class="text-center">GAME FEATURES</h1><br/><br/>
                <p class="lead">
                    <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span> An immersive environment for <strong>exploration</strong> with a mystery-adventure story and <strong>science-based puzzles.</strong>
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span> Plenty of <strong>scientific models</strong> within the game environment for investigation and conducting your own experiments.
                </p>
                <p class="lead">
                    <span class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></span> A <strong>journal</strong> that reads like a mystery novel, while providing insight into the history of astronomy and mechanics from the ancient Greeks to Newton, and clues for solving the puzzles.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at background-size property, I think you should use background-size:'cover' to fullfill the whole area

Comment: I used background size cover as you can see 
Image as seen in 1366x760 screen

Image as seen in 1920x1080 screen

The problem for me is the same image is seen differently in different browser settings. The section below the first image appears in the 1080p resolution screen and I don't see a way to mitigate this. Any idea how to do this?

This is the .css file

/* Home Style */
tf-home{

background: url(../images/OdysseyTitleImage.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #cfcfcf;
}

Comment: true, so I think the problem is on the overlay height. Try to make it 100% height so it cover the whole screen size.

Comment: So just change 750 px to 100%?

Comment: Thanks Jordi fixed it.

Comment: Jordi, I had to use 1080 px to fix it actually, 100% does not work.

Comment: if fixed height works for you it's ok, but always try to work with %. So making this div height to work with `%` it's another question (first you should look at it's parent css properties). In another hand, you can try to use `100vh`, but I'm not sure of `vh` compatibilities.